# Regex for combining 4 conditions with a logical AND operator

Tags: regex

I need to figure out a regex that tests for 4 strings to see if they do not exist in my input value.

For eg, I wish to capture all inputs that do not exactly match `/aaa`, `bbb`, `/ccc` or `/ddd` in them.

So valid strings would be `/dd`, `/dddd` and so on
and invalid strings would be `/aaa`, `/bbb`, `/ccc`, `/ddd`.

I am using the below regex for this:

```
^((?!\/aaa)(?!\/bbb).)*$
```

This works for any 2 strings as above, but if I add 4 of such capturing groups, then it won't work.

Comment: you mean that don't exactly match the unwanted like the pattern: [`^(?!\/(?:aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd)$).+`](https://regex101.com/r/CtHId4/2)

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I shall be using Javascript to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the positional marker `\b` to ensure the next position is the boundary of the word, and use the OR operator `|` in your `not` group to include multiple words to ignore:

```
^(?!\/aaa\b|\/bbb\b|\/ccc\b|\/ddd\b).*?$
```

Assuming this is for some command line interface, you can even ignore lines that are NOT commands by moving the / outside of the group.

```
^\/(?!aaa\b|bbb\b|ccc\b|ddd\b).*?$
```

You can see this in action, and what it will and will not capture, here:

https://regex101.com/r/3HFafX/3/

Answer (score 1):

You might make use of a capturing group with a character class and a backreference to that group:

```
^(?!/([a-d])\1{2}$).*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not

  - `/([a-d])\1{2}$`  Match `/`, capture any of the listed in the character class and repeat the backreference to that group 2 times and assert end of the string
- `)` Close negative lookahead
- `.*` Match any char 0+ times
- `$` Assert end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rtMdKo/1)

If you don't want to match empty strings you could use `+` as a quantifier instead of `*`.